# HP/Agilent Power Supply Age

Tags: power-supply, equipment, history

All,

I know this isn't likely a pure electrical engineering question, but it is about a tool that may have been found in a lab, or that someone here knows about.

I recently ordered a used HP/Agilent (actually, just HP) 6200B DC power supply off of eBay, and it arrived today. All of the knobs, switches, and lights work. I need to make sure everything's still on the money with a nice multimeter, but other than that, everything seems in good order.

Now, I just want to know approximately how old it is. Agilent's website has a .pdf of the user's manual with a revision date of 1966. HP spun off Agilent in the late 90s. It was definitely built between those two dates, but that's quite a bit of room.

Below are pictures of the unit itself. I've included the serial number in case anyone knows how the production run dates correspond to it. I've also looked at the circuit board... the traces are really "loose" instead of the tight, precisely-packed circuits you see today. Anyone have an idea of a range of when this unit was made?

[image: front]
[image: inside]
[image: serial number]
[image: circuit close]

Comment: You can roughly date HP/Agilent equipment from the 90's and 2000's by the shade of grey it came in. They adjusted the color just a bit lighter every couple of years. But I think this guy is too old for that scheme to work. If you can find the service manual, it may give a rundown of serial number ranges and dates for various design changes.

Comment: @ThePhoton, unfortunately, it's probably long gone. I surely didn't receive it.

I did notice that there was the user guide online at [this website](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/06200-90001.pdf). There's something in there about the date code but I'm not sure how it's to be construed.

Comment: Why does it matter how old it is? Aside from intellectual curiosity, and the possible need to replace the dried old electrolytics, those power supplies are as good today as they were when they were built. THey are excellent devices.

Comment: Logopedia says that HP logo was used post 1981:;http://logos.wikia.com/wiki/Hewlett-Packard. On the PCB in the 3rd pic I see what looks like "8431": - 31st week of '84?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the numbers are anything like on HP calculators the unit might have been built ca 1984 according to the site mentioned below.

> **Decoding Serial Numbers**
>
> Numbers are in the format YYWWC##### where
>
> YY    Is the number of years since 1960.
>
> WW    Is the week (roughly) in which the unit was made. YYWW is not always exact and sometimes may have gone weeks or months without changing.
>
> C    Is the country code: A = America (USA), B = Brazil, G = Germany, J = Japan, S = Singapore, M = Malaysia or Indonesia.
>
> # The serial number within the specified week and year. (This is not included in the Earliest Serial Numbers section because all are assumed to start at 0 or 1.)
>
> Example: The museum's HP-94F is serial number 2622J00025 indicating that it is the 25th unit made in Japan in the 22nd week of 1986.

Source: http://www.hpmuseum.org/collect.htm